# resize image respecting a min width / height and max width / height in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, resize, min

I have this function that resizes an image (after that I have some other stuff to rotate and crop to a square.
The problem here is I want the user be able to post images that are at least 640x640. What happens with this function is that if a user posts a 1080X1920 image (iphone picture), it will resize it to 562 X 1000 and then (with not shown code) it will be cropped to 562 X 562 ... The server will so refuse the image because it's smaller then 640X640. 
Can anyone help me improve this function so that it will return max width and height 1000 X 1000 but also respect a min width and height 640 X 640 ?
By experimenting I found that if I set the Max Width and Height to 1138 the same 1080X1920 px image will be cropped to 640X640 but that is not acceptable solution. Any clue?

```
img.onload = function () {
            var width = img.width,
                height = img.height,
                canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                start_Y,
                start_X;

            console.log( width, "  ", height);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;

            // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
            if ([5, 6, 7, 8].indexOf(srcOrientation) > -1) {
                if (width > height) {
                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                        width = MAX_WIDTH;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                    }
                }
                canvas.width = height;
                canvas.height = width;

                console.log(canvas.width, " ", canvas.height);

            } else {

                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;

                console.log(canvas.width, " ", canvas.height);
                }
}
```

maybe I found a way, I modified the function like this:

```
        img.onload = function () {
            var width = img.width,
                height = img.height,
                canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
                start_Y,
                start_X;


            var MAX_WIDTH = 1000;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 1000;

            var MIN_WIDTH = 640;
            var MIN_HEIGHT = 640;

            var ratio;

            // set proper canvas dimensions before transform & export
            if ([5, 6, 7, 8].indexOf(srcOrientation) > -1) {
                if (width > height) {

                    console.log('w > h');

                    if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                        height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;

                        if(height < MIN_HEIGHT){

                            ratio = MIN_HEIGHT / height;

                            height = MIN_HEIGHT;

                            width = MAX_WIDTH * ratio;


                        }else{

                            width = MAX_WIDTH;

                        }


                    }
                } else {

                    console.log('h > w');

                    if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                        width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;

                        if(width < MIN_WIDTH){

                            ratio = MIN_WIDTH / width;

                            width = MIN_WIDTH;

                            height = MIN_HEIGHT * ratio;

                        }else{

                            height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                        }


                    }
                }
                canvas.width = height;
                canvas.height = width;

                console.log(canvas.width, " ", canvas.height);

            } else {

                console.log('other Orientations');

                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;

                    if(width < MIN_WIDTH){

                        ratio = MIN_WIDTH / width;

                        width = MIN_WIDTH;

                        height = MAX_HEIGHT * ratio;


                    }else{

                        height = MAX_HEIGHT;

                    }


                }
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;

                console.log(canvas.width, " ", canvas.height);
            }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, you want the final square image to have a size of 640 to 1000. Which means if both dimensions are > 1000, you simply resize to 1000, with the other dimension being greater. Meaning a 1920x1080 image will get downsized to 1778 x 1000. Cropping this will get you a 1000x1000 square.

Comment: yes you are correct. This is what happens now, you will get a 1000X1000 square but how to constrain the minimum to 640 ?

Comment: If this is what happens now, why does your question say something completely different is happening to a 1920x1080 image?

Comment: I am not talking about 1920x1080 but 1080x1920, please check

Comment: Oh, I see. There's no need to distinguish between the two formats when it comes to calculating the resizing: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/xvz6xyhv/

Comment: ok, but that doesn't take into account srcOrientation cases

Comment: I found a simple solution for using my existing function. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Did you look at the example code I provided? You're splitting this into 4 cases, but is that really necessary? The `srcOrientation`, whatever it is, shouldn't change the fact that the image is cropped to a square in all cases, right?

Comment: Well no because if you don't take orientation into count you will end cropping wrong. I tried your code and it doesn't adapt to my cropping code as pics will be drawn off in many cases.

Comment: Cropping a rectangle down to the center square doesn't require branching into landscape and portrait either. Your solution may be simple, but it's long-winded and error prone.

Comment: After resize the context is transformed to correct orientation. With this solution every case (1 to 8, portrait and landscape) is rendered correctly. I'll post a paste later so that you can see the rest of the code and let me know what you think. If you want.

Comment: @ChrisG here's the paste: https://pastebin.com/JCf8dSEH  ... I checked functionality with these example images: https://github.com/recurser/exif-orientation-examples

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate a ratio like this when width is bigger than height

```
var ratio = 640 / height;
```

Or

```
var ratio = 640 / width;
```

Having this ratio you can calculate the other value

```
Height = ratio × height;
Width = ratio × width;
```

After this you have a redized image / element.

Comment: Yes thanks, I already figured out. I updated my question with a solution. Check it out.